# Linq where clause doesn't work in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, where-clause

This code doesn't work (returns null):

```
var result = context.Data
                    .Select(x => x)
                    .Where(x => x.ID == 1)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

But this:

```
var result = context.Data.Take(1);
```

works.

My question is why while I am using EF and the `context.Data` returns an `IEnumerable<Data>` the first code doesn't work? (And yes, the data contains element with ID equals 1)

Comment: the `Select` is redundant and the `Where` can be replaced with the `FirstOrDefault`. No real surprise the `Take` "works" as long as you got data in your table, but the where - just means no element with `ID == 1`

Comment: As an aside, you can vastly simplify to `context.Data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == 1);`.

Comment: if context.Data returns an IEnumerable, that has nothing to do with EF or LINQ2SQL. Also, both statements do vastly different things. the first "should" return the first object with the Id==1, or null if none exists, the second should return a List containing the first object, no condition applied.

Comment: use .ToList() to convert the enumerable to List

Comment: What is the result of `context.Data.Take(1).ID`?

Comment: What you mean by "works"? `Take(1)` will return `IEnumerable<T>` where `FirstOrDefault` will return instance of `T`. How you check that `Take` works?

Comment: @ErikPhilips - `Take(1).ID` will not compile

Comment: If you checking both results for being `null`, then `Take` will never return `null`, `Take` will return empty collection if there are no items.

Comment: As others have said it all boils down to what you want.  If you want a 'collection' (IEnumerable, List, Array, etc) you can have a collection with a single element.  If you do a First, Last, Single, etc.  That is an extension method that gets an individual item in that collection, that may or may not be overloaded with a predicate.  If I want a single Item but still a collection I could do context.Where(x => x.ID == 1).ToList() (minus First());  I made a very narrowing scope with my predicate to be a single item(unless you have multiple ID's with the same value) but it's still a collection.

Comment: OK, but FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID==1) also doesnt work, so?

Comment: It shouldn't work in a method as it will not be the same return type as your method expects.  It is returning an object of T when you expect an IEnumerable<T>.  They are different objects.   Set your return to 'object' and it will 'work'(compile) but not as you expect.

Comment: It compiles even now, but it returns null.

Comment: You probably have more code you are not displaying that may explain that behavior.  If you have a try catch or some type of 'FirstOrDefault' it may just swallow up what you are expecting a return null.  You may want to add more to your question with extra code.  The first line also has no need need of the 'Select' as that is used for defining WHAT you return (object, string, int, POCO).  A great tool to play with Linq with when you are learning is Linqpad.  https://www.linqpad.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question that has really nothing to do with Entity Framework but the nature of how LINQ works with collections with it's extension methods.  Let do a simple example in a console application in C#:

```
class Program
{
    public class Faker
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Faker(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ls = new List<Faker>
        {
            new Faker(1, "A"),
            new Faker(2, "B")
        };

        Faker singleItem = ls.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
        IEnumerable<Faker> collectionWithSingleItem = ls.Where(x => x.Id == 1);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

When I pause under 'Locals' I see the variables populated as such:

[image]

Comment: You are right, but I have another question why when I type x.Name="Name"  instead of ID it doesn't work?

Comment: There is no "Name" just "A" or "B" in my example as a property of Name off of the POCO Faker.  It would only work for a lambda like (x => x.Name == "A").  A single equals in .NET would be assignment and not determination of equality.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is : it should work. Although your line could be optimized to :

```
var v = context.Data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == 1);
```

So, basically there is no `ID == 1` in your database, or you misspelled something.

If you wanted a `IEnumerable<T>` type then :

```
var v = context.Data.Where(x => x.ID == 1);
```

But I'd rather use list :

```
var v = context.Data.Where(x => x.ID == 1).ToList();
```

Comment: As i said, there is no ID == 1 in your database

Comment: There is ID==1 in my database. When I get all elements I can with if clause get the element I want to.

Comment: Well, include the if part in your question if you want further help

Comment: When searching for a specific element with a specific Id, you use FirstOrDefault, not where clauses, and not executing with ToList, you use Where clauses when for instance you're searching for Homes in a certain district, where you expect a collection of results back

Comment: @AydinAdn I already know all that, i was showing how to make your query return different types (in case there would be 2 line with ID == 1, but in that case again, it's would be a bad database design)